# Lua как используя unpack найти максимальное по модулю отрицательное число в строке таблице

Tags: lua

Lua как используя `unpack` найти максимальное по модулю отрицательное число в строке таблице?

```
os.setlocale(""); -- Установка корректной кодировки

tbl = { { "C",       2,     1,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0    },
        { "базис",   1,     2,     3,     4,     5,    6,   "b"   },
        {    3,     -4,    -6,     1,     0,     0,    0,   -20   },
        {    4,     -2,     5,     0,     1,     0,    0,    27   },
        {    5,      7,     5,     0,     0,     1,    0,    63   },
        {    6,      3,    -2,     0,     0,     0,    1,    23   },
        {  "d",                                                   } }

print( math.max(unpack(tbl[2], 2, #tbl[1] - 1)) )

print( math.max(unpack(tbl[3])) )
```

Наверное это можно сделать с помощью возможностей `unpack`, чтобы не перебирать вручную элементы строки таблицы.

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: unpack просто формирует кортеж из таблицы.  а вам нужна функция, которая оставит числа и выбросит строки?

Comment: `максимальное по модулю отрицательное число` ищется через min, а не max

Comment: Как сделать функцию которая на вход принимает кортеж так же как math.max? И как перебирать элементы этого кортежа? Это же не таблица, а кортеж. Вот что мне нужно. @ESkri

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тут поможет метатаблица для чисел

```
local tbl = {
   { "C",       2,     1,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0    },
   { "базис",   1,     2,     3,     4,     5,    6,   "b"   },
   {    3,     -4,    -6,     1,     0,     0,    0,   -20   },
   {    4,     -2,     5,     0,     1,     0,    0,    27   },
   {    5,      7,     5,     0,     0,     1,    0,    63   },
   {    6,      3,    -2,     0,     0,     0,    1,    23   },
   {  "d",                                                   }
}

-- При сравнении любого числа с любой строкой число будет меньше строки
debug.setmetatable(0, {__lt = function (a,b) return type(a) == "number" end})

-- Строки будут считаться больше чисел и не повлияют на поиск минимального числа
for n, line in ipairs(tbl) do
   print(n, math.min(table.unpack(line)))
end
```

Выхлоп:

```
1     0
2     1
3   -20
4    -2
5     0
6    -2
7   d
```

Comment: Если нет отрицательных числе в строке, то возврат - положительное число, а должен быть nil. Я все сделал через переборы, но хочу попробовать улучшить с применением функционала Lua. @ESkri

Comment: строки и положительные числа, возвращаемые math.min, заменишь на nil ручками

Comment: Спасибо за помощь @ESkri

Comment: спасибо в репутацию не положишь ))))